# How to make a animation in PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.6

I'm trying to make a animation but at run it raise a error.

```
self.__animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, "geometry")
```

and raises this :/ anyone knows how to fix?

```
    self.__animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, "geometry")
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QPropertyAnimation(parent: QObject = None): too many arguments
  QPropertyAnimation(QObject, Union[QByteArray, bytes, bytearray], parent: QObject = None): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Comment: try with: `self.__animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'geometry')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `bytearray`, not `str`:

```
self.__animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'geometry')
```

Comment: OMFG, this work, in pyqt4 accept string :/ thank you so much.